# nativescript+angular livesync doesn't work on mac

Tags: ios, macos, nativescript-angular

The tutorial for ios DOES NOT WORK. Suggested fixes from stackoverflow DO NOT WORK. Live Sync does not update. Can someone please help? What do I need to do to get this running -- this has been a week of complete frustration.... thanks.

I'm using this tutorial, following for ios: 
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/cli-basics

The directory structure for the app directory is not noted correctly - for example, the home.component.ts file is actually located in  HelloWorld/platforms/ios/HelloWorld/app/app/home

When I update the home.component.ts file to the suggested content to display the apple image, the simulator does not refresh. Actionbar title never changes, image is never displayed - even if I try to load it locally. What's wrong?

Here is my tns and angular configs, running against most current mac os High Sierra:

TNS:

> tns doctor ✔ Getting environment information
>
> No issues were detected. ✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is
>   set and points to correct directory. ✔ Your adb from the Android SDK
>   is correctly installed. ✔ The Android SDK is installed. ✔ A compatible
>   Android SDK for compilation is found. ✔ Javac is installed and is
>   configured properly. ✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and
>   is configured properly. ✔ Xcode is installed and is configured
>   properly. ✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly. ✔
>   CocoaPods are installed. ✔ CocoaPods update is not required. ✔
>   CocoaPods are configured properly. ✔ Your current CocoaPods version is
>   newer than 1.0.0. ✔ Python installed and configured correctly. ✔ The
>   Python 'six' package is found. ✔ Getting NativeScript components
>   versions information... ✔ Component nativescript has 4.2.3 version and
>   is up to date.

ANGULAR:

> ng --version 
>   Angular CLI: 6.1.5 Node: 8.9.4 OS: darwin x64 Angular: 
>   ...
>
> Package                      Version
>   ------------------------------------------------------ @angular-devkit/architect    0.7.5 @angular-devkit/core         0.7.5
>   @angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.5 @schematics/angular          0.7.5
>   @schematics/update           0.7.5 rxjs                         6.3.2
>   typescript                   2.9.2

Comment: same problem, did you find an answer?

Comment: No, and that was 11 months ago. Will try to rework this again.

Comment: can you tell me, livesync doesn't work on your emulator or device (iphone)?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response - was running exactly as indicated in the linked tutorial. Have not circled back to test again but will try to.